# How to retain the old SSD Drive as a secondary drive during migration

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd

I'm upgrading from a 250 Gig SSD to a 1TB SSD. There's a handy migration tool from Samsung for this, and it has cloned my old SSD onto my new SSD. I did this via a eSata->USB connection. The old and new drives are now identical, named "C:", and are boot drives. (I haven't booted up or installed the new drive yet).
My system is a desktop Windows 8.1 64 bit system.

The instructions now recommend that I remove my old drive and install the new one. I'm positive this will work, but I would like to retain my old SSD as a secondary drive. However, as it has the same drive letter and is also a boot drive, I don't see a way to let it inside the PC. As the old SSD Drive is an mSata drive, I would prefer not having to physically remove it. Is there a way to achieve my goal of replacing the old 250 Gig mSata SSD with my new 1TB eSata SSD as the new "C:" boot drive while retaining my old SSD drive for an extra 250 Gigs of drive space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would carry out the following steps

1. Label the old hard drive with a different label e.g. Old (this way you know which one is the old drive)
2. Install the new drive
3. As you have 2 bootable drives you need to change the boot sequence within the BIOS to get the computer to boot using the new drive
4. Delete all partitions on old drive and reformat

You will then have both drives usable with the old drive empty